# Service schema is not detecting into Rich Results Test?

Tags: schema.org

I have added a service schema on my site. However, while testing into the **Rich Result Tool**, it's showing the Local business schema instead of the service schema. But it is still showing service schema into the **Structure Testing Tool**

**Rich Result Tool** - https://a.cl.ly/ApuG1mG4

**Structure Testing Tool** - https://a.cl.ly/4guOD8lZ

Is the service schema is supported by Google or not? If yes where we can see the result into Rich result?

Comment: Looks the Structure Testing Tool is being deprecated: https://www.business2community.com/brandviews/shelley-media-arts/goodbye-structure-data-testing-tool-how-to-use-the-rich-results-test-02327418

Answer (score 0):

The Rich Results Test only reports top level entities that generate Rich Results in Google. Service is not one of them.

LocalBusiness is a supported entity. Because of this the tool is promoting it to the top level in its report.

You can see this effect on any entities that have their own rich results. e.g. an aggregateReview might be in a product, but it gets reported on at the top level as it has its own snippet (stars).

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone interesteed in this topic.

For some time the validation tool for structured data from google needs a context and also theschema.org documentation specifies it... He estado luchando con eso durante aproximadamente una hora until I saw it and I fixed it adding:

```
"@context":"https://schema.org"
```

just before the rest of the schema:

The result:

```
<script id="jgc-structured-data" type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context":"https://schema.org",
    "@type":"Organization",
    "name":"Juan G Carmona",
    "legalName":"Juan G Carmona",
    "url":"https://jgcarmona.com",
    "logo":"https://jgcarmona.com/img/jgc-log-w.png","
    foundingDate":"1981",
    "address":{
        "@type":"PostalAddress",
        "addressLocality":"Paracuellos de Jarama",
        "addressRegion":"Madrid",
        "postalCode":"28061",
        "addressCountry":"Spain"
    },
    "contactPoint":{
        "@type":"ContactPoint",
        "contactType":"customer service",      
        "email":"juan@jgcarmona.com"
    },
    "sameAs":[
             "http://www.linkedin.com/in/juangarciacarmona",
        ]
}
</script>
```